# How to call events in delphi without user intervention?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have one button on my form. Following is the click event of that button

```
procedure Form1.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
//Do something
end;
```

This event will be called only when I click the button, right?

How can I call this event automatically without any user intervention?

Comment: See [Why is it bad practice to call an eventhandler from code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/956255/33732), which includes a description of three ways of manually triggering event handlers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call this event in code like any other method.

```
...
btnOkClick(Self.btnOk); // Sender in this case is the btnOk
...
```

The Sender can be whatever object you like or nil.

Comment: you did not call the event, you simply call a method. you can't call an event, you can only call the method that is related to an event.

Answer (score 20):

The best way to invoke the `OnClick` event handler attached to a control is to call the `Click` method on the control. Like this:

```
btnOK.Click;
```

Calling the event handler directly forces you to supply the `Sender` parameter. Calling the `Click` method gets the control to do all the work. The implementation of the windows message handler for a button click calls the `Click` method.

But I second the opinion expressed in whosrdaddy's answer. You should pull out the logic behind the button into a separate method.

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that fits perfect the question. OP question is about **events** and **not methods**. Maybe OP did not know the difference, but thats the way he asked :o)

Comment: It works for click on buttons but there is not such method on Panel for example. Also what about Resize event? How can I call a Resize event programmatically?

Comment: @Delmo Either call the event handler directly, or extract it into another method that you can call directly, and which the event handler calls.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan, I supposed this kind of solutions but I was asking for some method to "simulate" an event ocurrence.

Comment: As @SirRufo said, the question is about events, not methods.

Comment: @Delmo How else is the event handler going to be fired?

Comment: No longer allowed in 10.3 I get error can not access protected symbole , what is the alternative ?

Comment: @wei see final paragraph

Answer (score 17):

Do not put your businesslogic into event handlers. This will make your code unreadable when the application grows larger.

Normally you would do this:

```
procedure TForm1.DoSomething;
begin
 // do something
end;

procedure TForm1.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DoSomething;
end;
```

then all you need to do is call `DoSomething` from other parts in your code

Comment: Same effect as @LURDs answer, only cleaner code. You will thank yourself later if you do it this way, especially if `// do something` is moved to a separate unit, datamodule, business object.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - you are right. I am going to do like that. I asked this question only because I wanted to know the second way.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I am re-factoring a 100k LOC behemoth that was written this way, the guy before me needs to be punished :)

Comment: Or wrap all the business logic in its own object structure, not related to any GUI.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Yes that's something one would normally do :)